# Can't use PySide with Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyside

I have just installed Anaconda for Python 3 and then installed PySide by

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside
```

Then I tried to use it throw Anaconda's version of python and typed `import PySide` but gave me this error `ImportError: No module named 'PySide'`

But when I try the normal Interpreter of Python it works fine, So how could I make it work with Anaconda?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install it with `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyside
```

Comment: won't it get in conflict with the one i just installed ?

Comment: No Anaconda install into its own directory. You installed for the system Python.

Comment: Mine spyder went strange and said it requires pyside 1.2.0+. This is the solution helped me resolve the issue. Thanks.