# Is Pyside not compatible with python 3.6.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pyside

I followed the steps to install Pyside on my macOS 13.13.4 on `Python 3.6.4` on this [Github page](http://pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/macosx.html) but after runninng `pip install -U PySide`, I got the following error message which seems to indicate that Pyside is not compatible to `Python 3.6.4` ??:

```
mymacs-MacBook-Pro:~ mymac$ pip install -U PySide
Collecting PySide
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/ac/ca31db6f2225844d37a41b10615c3d371587677efd074db29855e7035de6/PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jq/yyp9q2fs1z5780k9l1_2ph4r0000gn/T/pip-install-zz9h16bx/PySide/
mymacs-MacBook-Pro:~ mymac$
```

Is I have anaconda, I looked at this [website](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyside) and this [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708923/cant-use-pyside-with-anaconda) I tried `conda install -c anaconda pyside` and `conda install -c conda-forge pyside` but both of them also threw this same error message:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- pyqt
- pyside
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The error message says very clearly: `only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]`.

Comment: Thank you @BoarGules. In between I did indeed read the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems according to [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362751/installing-pyside-for-python-3-6) that Pyside will not be updated for version of python 3.5+. Instead, Pyside2 should be installed. The Installation instructions can be found [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python)