# Broke my python installation, and reinstalls don't fix the problem

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pyside

I've been using Python for school for the last semester or so, and in between courses I wanted to experiment a bit with more game-oriented modules. Specifically, I was looking at PyGame, at the time. Somehow, I couldn't get it to work with my current installation, so I tried to download a previous version, and from there things spiralled a bit out of control.

I've been using Anaconda / Spyder, and now neither of them will start at all. At first, I got what appears to have been a common error from a few years ago: Neither of them could detect a module called PySide, which apparently caused some sort of problem during startup. (Reiterate: I only have the faintest idea of what I'm doing.) I tried all of the common solutions to the problem I could find, including:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling qt / pyqt
- Installing msgpack
- Trying to install pyside, and getting a compatibility error

I've also reinstalled anaconda completely, deleting all the files and the folders that I could find before doing so, and even on a fresh install the same problem is there. I'm running out of ideas. I would love some kind of direction of where to go.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708923/cant-use-pyside-with-anaconda, and then update your question if this does not help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ms-windows, deleting stuff is probably not sufficient to completely remove Anaconda. There will probably be stuff left in the registry. Use the [standard methods](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028054/windows-10-repair-or-remove-programs) to uninstall programs before trying to re-install them.

Some additional advice is to try the reference Python implementation from `python.org`. I used to be a fan of Anaconda but have had lots of trouble with it in the last year or so. Since a lot of popular modules now have packages for windows available with `pip`, I would give the regular python.org version a try.